# Need help in installing Microsoft GP 2010 on Windows Server 2012 VM

Tags: installation, microsoft-dynamics, prerequisites, dynamics-gp

EDIT: The below installation activity has been tried out in elevated mode (Run as Administrator).

When I am trying to install Microsoft GP 2010 on Windows Server 2012 VM, I am getting the following error

```
Component Dexterity Shared Components 11.0 has failed to install with the following error message:
"Fatal error during installation. "

The following components were successfully installed:
- .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

The following components were not installed:
- Microsoft Application Error Reporting 11.0
- Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10.0
- Open XML SDK 2.0 for Microsoft Office

The following components failed to install:
- Dexterity Shared Components 11.0

See the setup log file located at 'C:\Users\IRMSAD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VSD666C.tmp\install.log' for more information.
```

I have read this [article](http://blog.technotesdesk.com/microsoft-dynamics-gp-10-0-%E2%80%94-dexterity-shared-component-10-%E2%80%94-error/).

After reading the article I am not finding the respective frameworks to uninstall as my OS is Win-Server-2012 (wherein the .NET-framework comes in as "bundled"). So the above link, although it suggests a solution, does NOT seem to be helping me.

If any of you guys had a solution for it or at least a direction-pointer, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run the installation in elevated mode? (Run as Administrator)

Answer (score 0):

Disable User account control and Run the installation as an administrator. If that doesn't work you may need to copy the installation files to the local workstation.